# yum install failed and corrupted the original yum

Tags: linux, makefile, redhat, yum

I was trying to install yum-3.4.3 using commands make && make install, but it failed with showing the following log:

```
infra-bld4:/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3> make
for d in rpmUtils yum etc docs po; do make PYTHON=python -C $d; [ $? = 0 ] || exit 1 ; done
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/rpmUtils'
echo "Nothing to do"
Nothing to do
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/rpmUtils'
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/yum'
echo "Nothing to do"
Nothing to do
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/yum'
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/etc'
echo "Nothing to do"
Nothing to do
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/etc'
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/docs'
echo "Nothing to do"
Nothing to do
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/docs'
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/po'
msgfmt -o ca.mo ca.po -c
msgfmt: ca.po: field `Language-Team' still has initial default value
msgfmt: found 1 fatal error
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: *** [ca.mo] Error 1
make-3.79.1-p7[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3/po'
make-3.79.1-p7: *** [subdirs] Error 1
infra-bld4:/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3>
```

Because I tried to re-install the yum, but the installation failed half way, so bad thing is that I corrupted the original yum in the system. Anybody can help me recover the yum or re-install it will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a link.  I can't vouch for it because I have never had to reinstall yum.  http://hacktux.com/yum/force/reinstall

Comment: That isn't an installation failure that's a compilation failure. That shouldn't have touched anything on your system at all. What is the actual yum problem you are having? Why are you trying to install yum manually yourself?

Comment: @EtanReisner I used rpm to install the yum. But there are lots of dependencies, and then I installed some of them. Later I realised that too many dependencies were needed, so I gave up using that way. I downloaded a binary version in this link (http://yum.baseurl.org/download/3.4/yum-3.4.3.tar.gz), and tried to make && make install yum,  then it failed in some reasons I listed in my question log.

Comment: @EtanReisner Now when everytime I type yum, it shows error messages like:infra-bld4:/tmp/hxu2/yum-3.4.3> yum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 28, in ?
    import yummain
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 30, in ?
    from yum import logginglevels
ImportError: cannot import name logginglevels

Comment: That link is to the yum source. Running `make` does not install it. You would almost certainly have needed to install `make install` to do that. It seems more likely to me that installing (what probably amounted to) random RPMs is what broke your yum installation. You should probably try to figure out what all RPMs you manually installed and then go find the correct, distribution provided, RPMs for those packages and use rpm to force install them again.

Comment: Why were you trying to upgrade yum beyond what your distribution provided in the first place?

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for your reply! There is some config issues that yum can't properly work on my machine. So that's why I was trying to reinstall it. My stupidness! If I couldn't remember which dependencies I installed, in this case, is there any way that I can recover my poor yum? :(

Comment: @YatinSaraiya Thanks for your comments. The link you gave me is talking about using yum to force install and remove some package, but my yum is corupted, I need to forcely install yum:( Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gone through that problem so it was the best I could do.

Comment: What sort of "config issues"? And if you can remember where you got those random RPMs from you might be able to use that to figure out which they were. Also `rpm -Va` might give you some useful information about which packages are currently broken which might help you sort out which need to be installed. I'd start with reinstalling yum at least and then adding anything it complains about to your list as well.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thans Etan for your continuous help! I found the original distribution of my yum and can successfully restore my yum from that distribution. Because if we wanna install the latest version yum, there might be tons of dependencies needed to be installed as well. So in order to avoid such kind of dependencies issue, we'd better to choose to install the same version yum. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to uninstall
you can do rpm -e yum

then

Install it using:

## rpm -ivh yum-(version).rpm

If yum is working fine for local installations, but it's not able to access Red Hat Network, verify if the following packages are installed. If not, install them:

```
rhnsd
yum-rhn-plugin
yum-security
rhn-check
rhn-setup
rhn-setup-gnome
yum-downloadonly
rhn-client-tools
rhn-virtualization-common
rhn-virtualization-host
pirut
yum-updatesd
```