# make[1]: python: Command not found

Tags: python, redhat, yum

I am trying to install yum package (yum-3.4.3.tar.gz) as yum got corrupted in the unix machine. While installing it is failing with `python: Command not found` error. When execute python command, it is getting python console.

```
make

for d in rpmUtils yum etc docs po; do make PYTHON=python -C $d; [ $? = 0 ] || exit 1 ; done
make[1]: python: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/rpmUtils'
make[1]: python: Command not found
echo "Nothing to do"
Nothing to do
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/rpmUtils'
make[1]: python: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/yum'
make[1]: python: Command not found
echo "Nothing to do"
Nothing to do
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/yum'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/etc'
echo "Nothing to do"
Nothing to do
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/etc'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/docs'
echo "Nothing to do"
Nothing to do
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/docs'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/po'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/yum-3.4.3/po'
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: This may help (https://stackoverflow.com/q/17665790)